# multiple looping using mustache.js

Tags: mustache

This is my json.. how can i retrieve the values of "definition" as iterated...

how can i loop through it.. I just want to know how iterate this json using mustache.js...
guys Please help me out...

```
{
  "1": {
    "word": "gun",
    "pos": "verb-transitive",
    "attrtxt": "from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition",
    "1": {enter code here
      "definition": "A weapon consisting of a metal tube from which a projectile is fired at high velocity into a relatively flat trajectory."
    },
    "2": {
      "definition": "A cannon with a long barrel and a relatively low angle of fire."
    },
    "3": {
      "definition": "A portable firearm, such as a rifle or revolver."
    },
    "4": {
      "definition": "A device resembling a firearm or cannon, as in its ability to project something, such as grease, under pressure or at great speed."
    },
    "5": {
      "definition": "A discharge of a firearm or cannon as a signal or salute."
    },
    "6": {
      "definition": "One, such as a hunter, who carries or uses a gun."
    },
    "7": {
      "definition": "A person skilled in the use of a gun."
    },
    "8": {
      "definition": "A professional killer:  a hired gun. "
    },
    "9": {
      "definition": "The throttle of an engine, as of an automobile."
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "1": {
      "definition": "To shoot (a person):  a bank robber who was gunned down by the police. "
    },
    "word": "gun",
    "pos": "verb-intransitive",
    "attrtxt": "from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition",
    "2": {
      "definition": "To open the throttle of (an engine) so as to accelerate:  gunned the engine and sped off. "
    },
    "3": {
      "definition": "Maine   To hunt (game)."
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to reformat the JSON?  Having everything as a specific named element means using tags like:

```
{{1.1.definition}}
```

The block tags allow you to loop, but the specific names limit that to things like:

```
{{#1}}{{word}}{{/1}}
```

Formatting it with arrays would make looping over it much easier:

```
{
    "Words" : [{
            "word" : "gun",
            "pos" : "verb-transitive",
            "attrtxt" : "from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition",
            "definitions" : [
                "A weapon consisting of a metal tube from which a projectile is fired at high velocity into a relatively flat trajectory.",
                "A cannon with a long barrel and a relatively low angle of fire.",
                "A portable firearm, such as a rifle or revolver.",
                "A device resembling a firearm or cannon, as in its ability to project something, such as grease, under pressure or at great speed.",
                "A discharge of a firearm or cannon as a signal or salute.",
                "One, such as a hunter, who carries or uses a gun.",
                "A person skilled in the use of a gun.",
                "A professional killer:  a hired gun. ",
                "The throttle of an engine, as of an automobile."
            ]
        }, {
            "word" : "gun",
            "pos" : "verb-intransitive",
            "attrtxt" : "from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition",
            "definitions" : [
                "To shoot (a person):  a bank robber who was gunned down by the police. ",
                "To open the throttle of (an engine) so as to accelerate:  gunned the engine and sped off. ",
                "Maine   To hunt (game)."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```